# SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition with PowerBI and Power View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, powerbi

I want to know if Power View works with SQL Server 2014 Standard edition. I checked on msdn link and it provides some useful information but I am still confused on Power View functionality. If i install SQL 2014 standard edition, and report server in SharePoint mode, would Power View work with standard? Also, I want to know if PowerBI works with Standard edition? thanks in advance

Comment: [This MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2014/01/02/business-intelligence-in-sql-server-2014-power-view-for-multidimensional-models/) suggests yes, and was the first result when I Googled for this. Have you tried going ahead and installing SQL 2014 and seeing whether it works for you? Probably quicker than asking here and waiting for someone to either do that for you, or search it online.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You need Enterprise or Business Intelligence edition per this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx#Reporting). Search for Power View on that page.